# Warning: mysqli_connect(): (28000/1045): Access denied for

Tags: mysql, database

I just got two errors on my web page. And I'm not very used to mess with database, mysql and so I need you to help me!

> Warning: mysqli_connect(): (28000/1045): Access denied for user 'u467224226_yjygu'@'10.1.2.19' (using password: YES) in /home/u467224226/public_html/galeria/api.php on line 8
>
> Warning: mysqli_error() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, boolean given in /home/u467224226/public_html/galeria/api.php on line 8

Here's the code.

```
<?php // connect to the database $user_name = ""; $password = ""; $database = ""; $host_name = "localhost";

$con = mysqli_connect($host_name ,$user_name ,$password,$database) or die("Error " .       mysqli_error($con)); //check connection

echo "Connection opened";

mysql_close($con); ?>

<?php   require_once('include/config.inc.php');     header("Content-type: application/x-javascript");
    
    
            $connect = mysql_connect($CONFIG['dbserver'],$CONFIG['dbuser'],$CONFIG['dbpass'])       or die('Erro ao conectar ao servidor');     $connect_db = mysql_select_db($CONFIG['dbname'], $connect)      or die ('Erro ao conectar ao banco de dados');
            
                
                $resultado = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `cpg_albums` ORDER BY `cpg_albums`.`aid` DESC LIMIT 0 , 4", $connect)

                    or die('Nenhum album encontrado com esta query');
                                        
                    echo 'document.write(\'';
                    
                    if(mysql_num_rows($resultado) == 0){
                        echo 'Nenhum Ã¡lbum cadastrado';
                    } else { echo '<section id="ultimas_fotos">  ';
                        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($resultado)){
                            echo ' ';
                                $album_id = $row['aid'];
                                $subresult = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `cpg_pictures` where aid=$album_id order by pid DESC LIMIT 0, 20");
                                
                                if(mysql_num_rows($subresult) == 0){
                                    $album_img = "http://tisdalephotos.com/images/thumbs/thumb_nopic.png";
                                } else {
                                    while($subrow = mysql_fetch_array($subresult)){
                                        $album_img = "http://tisdalephotos.com/albums/".$subrow['filepath'].'thumb_'.$subrow['filename'] .$subrow['datebrowse'];
                                                                                
                                    }
                                }
                                
                                echo '<div id="ultalb"><a href="http://tisdalephotos.com/thumbnails.php?album='.$album_id.' "><img src="'.$album_img.'" alt="" /></a><div id="ultalbt"><a href="http://tisdalephotos.com/thumbnails.php?album='.$album_id.' ">+</a></div></div>';   
                                
                            echo '';
                        }
                    }

echo '</tr></section>';
                    echo '\');';
                            ?>
```

Comment: Do you have any ideas as to what it might be? SO is not just a debugging service.

Comment: wrong login information (password)?

Comment: If you found an answer provided here helpful, please upvote and/or mark as accepted, so that other users with a similar question can benefit.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've got the password correct.

Does your user have the correct permissions? Login as root then run:

```
select Host, User from mysql.user;
```

See what is listed for your user.

If it's missing, you can run:

```
CREATE USER 'u467224226_yjygu'@'%%' IDENTIFIED BY 'PASSWORD';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'u467224226_yjygu'@'%%';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```